# iPhone: Getting date from date picker

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, notifications, datepicker

I wrote an app that allows users to enter in a date on a date picker, and the app will alert the user 36 hours before that date arrives. My issue is in the `dateFromString:`. I'm not sure what to put in there. Here is the code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm'/'dd'/'yyyy"];
NSDate *eventDate=[dateFormatter dateFromString: ]; 

localNotif.fireDate = [eventDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-13*60*60];
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];


localNotif.alertBody = @"Event tommorow!";

localNotif.alertAction = nil;

localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotif];    

return YES;
```

}

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Edit: Here is some additional code that I'm using to save the date they entered on the date picker if that helps:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSDate *storedDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DatePickerViewController.selectedDate"];

    [self.datePicker setDate:storedDate animated:NO];
}
```

And this is the method that saves the data:

```
- (IBAction)dateChanged:(id)sender {

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSDate *selectedDate = [self.datePicker date];

[defaults setObject:selectedDate forKey:@"DatePickerViewController.selectedDate"];}
```

Comment: You have give the event date as string...it will convert into date itself...in this format @"mm//dd/yyyy"...

Comment: Oh ok, thank you. The user enters in the date themselves, which is what makes it tricky for me. Do you know how I would go about getting the date they entered, and setting it in the `dateFromString` area?

Comment: Sorry i dont get it...i dont know that too exactly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need a string? 
After making

`[defaults setObject:selectedDate forKey:@"DatePickerViewController.selectedDate"];`

you can access your date just like

```
NSDate* eventDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DatePickerViewController.selectedDate"];
```

Using strings is not so nice with date - you should care about locale and time formats (12 hours or 24 hours) etc.

Comment: Oh awesome, thank you so much. So, should I just delete the `NSDate *eventDate=[dateFormatter dateFromString: ];` and switch it to `NSDate* eventDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DatePickerViewController.selectedDate"];`?

Comment: Yes, just add checking for nil. First time you'll launch your app on the device there will be no stored date in userDefaults.

Comment: Awesome thanks, yeah that may be why my app crashes when I click on the tab with the date picker. How do I check for nil? Sorry for the beginner question.

Comment: `NSDate* eventDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DatePickerViewController.selectedDate"];
if (eventDate!=nil)
{
//Your code here
}`

Sorry for bad formatting, it's just comment.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! You helped me out tremendously!

Comment: If (eventDate == nil) and you want to get current time, use `eventDate  = [NSDate date];`
[NSDate description](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: @Павел Оганесян Hey, I have a question about the objectForKey: area. What should I put in there, the name of my nib file? Thank you.

Comment: It should be the same key that you've put in a 
`[defaults setObject:selectedDate forKey:@"DatePickerViewController.selectedDate"];` 
It is just a string that helps you to identify objects you've stored in userDefaults.

Comment: @Павел Оганесян Awesome thank you. I tried that but it still doesn't seem to work. I created another thread about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958898/iphone-local-notifications-wont-appear/